# php best way to show notification after redirect

Tags: php, session

I need to Display notification message after header redirect page. i redirect page using this function :

```
function Redirect($url) {
if(!headers_sent()) {
    //If headers not sent yet... then do php redirect
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit;
} else {
    //If headers are sent... do javascript redirect... if javascript disabled, do html redirect.
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<noscript>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
    echo '</noscript>';
    exit;
}
   }
```

I insert error in php `SESSION` like this :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['errors'] = array();

...

array_push($_SESSION['errors'], "<span style = 'color:green;'>Success!</span>");
Redirect("somepage.php"); // OR header("Location: somepage.php");
```

And for display notification:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['errors']) && count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0) {
    foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $k => $v)
        echo($v . "<br/>");
    unset($_SESSION['errors']);
}
```

Put notification in `SESSION` is safe and good way? if not, what's best way for show notification after header redirect ?!

Comment: Those are known as "Flash Messages", and yes, your approach is correct. See also http://mikeeverhart.net/php/session-based-flash-messages/.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library just for this type of projects https://github.com/tamtamchik/simple-flash.

Once you have it installed you can do this:

```
// put message not session
flash('Some error message', 'error');

// print it after redirect
echo flash()->display();
```

It'll generate [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) friendly alert messages.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's good way.
You need's something, that may save data through requests. In php we have cookie and session. Cookie it's bad idea for that, session good.
You may make class for this, and show notifications like this:

```
if ($oNotification->hasNotification('key'))
{
$oNotification->showNotification('key');
}
```

For example, in Yii Framework in User Module exists "flashes" working with sessions

Comment: And then when displayed remove the message from the session.

Comment: exactly =) In example he made this.